# Custom UI styling for Angular 2 ng2-auto-complete component

Tags: css, angular

To create a TypeAhead component , I am making use of Angular2 ng2-auto-complete component. I was able to get the functionality correct.
Now I want to style it. Meaning I want to add a animation on an arrow so that when the dropdown is displayed, the arrow inverts.

Should I use `list-formatter` option from ng2-auto-complete component? If yes, how do I use it? I tried using a css class where I use animations, but it did not work.

Also if I simply add the icon, `z-index` does not let me bring the icon to the front. Meaning the icon is present but hidden behind the typeahead component.

This is my HTML code

```
<input ng2-auto-complete id="inputEvent" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="model" ngModel
     name="event" #event="ngModel" [source]="items" value-property-name=null display-property-name="name" (valueChanged)="onSelect($event)"/>
<span class="icon-arrow-down"></span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the question posted by me, I was trying to add an external icon to show on the typeahead component to mimic how a `<button class="btn dropdown-button"></button>` would look.

So I first used `<i></i>` and then added an overlay class to it.

My HTML is,

```
<i class="fa fa-lg icon-arrow overlay"></i>
<input ng2-auto-complete class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="model" ngModel
     name="typeahead" #typeahead="ngModel" [source]="values" value-property-name=null display-property-name="name" (valueChanged)="onSelect($event)"/>
```

CSS,

```
.overlay{
   position: absolute;
   top: 15px;
   left: 195px;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   z-index: 10;
   font-size:11px
}
```